# Low-side active clamp forward converters with synchronous rectification

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, switch-mode-power-supply

I'd like to analyse the active clamp forward circuit, and I read the paper which called [*Analysis and Implementation of Low-side Active Clamp Forward Converters with Synchronous Rectification*](http://120.114.52.219/bitstream/987654321/6946/1/2007IECON+TD-012718.pdf)

Does anyone know how to derive equations 3 and 4? I know I need to draw the equivalent circuit first, but I don't know how to solve this circuit to get equations 3 and 4. Could you give me some advice?

[image]

[image]

Update:

[image]

Comment: it comes from KVL, KCL

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Yes, I know, but I can get the same result. so I very confused where I do wrong.

Comment: What assumptions did you make for what happens when t=t1 time in Stage 2 and Inductor current = sin ?  Show your work in question.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I use Mathcad to solve the euation, but the result is not the same as paper.

Comment: Show your work.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I update my Mathcad equation, please check.

Comment: Define your initial conditions with equation F(s) or f(t) with KVL, KCL

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 What does your mean

Comment: F(s) is the Fourier transform , K stands for Kirchoff method

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 But I still cannot get the answer as the paper